# Error code: 0xC000000D for Smb2SetInfoRequest

Tags: smb, jcifs

I'm using jcifs-ng (https://github.com/AgNO3/jcifs-ng) and implementing SMB2 SET_INFO request for security info, particularly trying to set the file owner. I implemented a BasicFileInformation class that follows the security descriptor specification defined in MS-DTYP section 2.4.6. However, I get that invalid parameter error. Is there a way to debug this so that I can pinpoint which parameter is incorrect?

Also, I'm using a BitSet for the Control field and setting bits starting with index 0 for the SR bit. Is that the correct order?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Wireshark to browse your request. Wireshark has good dissectors for ACLs.

Btw, MS states that the ACL format is internal and the right way to access (create) it is using Win API. "Technically correct, absolutely useless" when it comes to a network message which is originated in a non-windows environment. Good news are that the ACL format did not change for years.

Comment: Thanks I’ll check out Wireshark. Would I run that on the CIFS share or client?